# Emailing and forwarding user to a confirmation

Tags: php, javascript, html, redirect

I am trying to accomplish 2 things in my html form: sending an email to a user and forwarding the user to a confirmation page. I am aware that the submit button can send emails. I am also aware that it can forward the user to a confirmation page. I have tested both **separately** and they work. How do I get the form to accomplish both at the same time. For example:

```
<form action="processData.php" method="get">

STUFF

</form>
```

The above will send data to a php file that sends an email. The below will forward the user to a page called "Confirm" when the submit button is clicked.

```
<form action="Confirm">

STUFF

</form>
```

Comment: Why do you need a form to display a confirmation? Forms are for gathering input.

The PHP file that receives your form is responsible for directing the user to a confirmation page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to redirect the user after you're done processing the user data in `processData.php`.

You can accomplish this with using something like

```
Header("Location: confirmation.php");
```

Or

```
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=confirmation.php">';
```

Comment: I tried entering this line of code into my php code and it does not work. Maybe I should have mentioned this but I am doing all of this in Wordpress but I figured that if they work separately this should work as well

Comment: Try this: echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=confirmation.php">';

Answer (score 0):

`processData.php` should contain a redirect such as:

```
header('Location: http://www.mydomain.com?source=success');
```

Comment: I tried entering this line of code into my php code and it does not work. Maybe I should have mentioned this but I am doing all of this in Wordpress but I figured that if they work separately this should work as well